# ajax with spring mvc always getting error

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring

Every request ajax getting an error. 
Ajax function:

```
function doAjax() {
            var inputText = $("#info").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'ajax',
//                data: ({text: inputText}), 
                dataType: 'json',
                data: 'text='+inputText,
                success: function (response) {
                    $("#result_info").text(response);
                }
               error: function (e) {
                    alert('error' + e.responseText);
                }
            });
        }
```

Java Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/ajax"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String showText(@RequestParam String text) {
    System.out.println(text);
    String returnText = "empty";
    if (!text.isEmpty()) {
        returnText = " response: " + text;
    }

    return returnText;
}
```

Besides this question could you tell what is the difference between in ajax query

```
data: ({text: inputText}), 
data: 'text='+inputText,
```

Comment: Whar is the error message?

Comment: Did you want response in json format? if you don't want change dataType:'text' then change your URL also and then try

Comment: It send me each time "error" + returnText which is defined in java method. As fact my message(response) comes to page, but just in error part and in e.responseText

Comment: As I read to get response in json enough just add this dependency  org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl

Comment: try something like this. remove data part. append input data into url like below. 'ajax?text='+inputText

Comment: can you please share the error massage.It will be easy to get the coz of the problem

Comment: @rachana but if  I use json dataType, it will also return error.. How to avoid this?

Comment: @jenius can you please share the error massage so that i can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular case it's better to change dataType to html instead of json. I solved it.